# How to do YUI 3 Slider widget to be 100% width

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

Is there a way to set `YUI 3 Slider widget` to be `100% width`?
In the [documentatiotn](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/slider/), `length` attribute is set in `px`. I tryed with `%`, but not work.

```
YUI().use('slider', function (Y) {
    var interval;
    var slider = new Y.Slider({
        min         : 0,
        max         : 3000,
        value       : 3000,
        length  : '100%'
    });
});
```

My site is responsive and my goal is to use only 1 slider in all media query break points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the `slider` length, the UI will be [updated automatically](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/files/slider_js_slider-base.js.html#l525).

This means you can set the length at creation time and later change it if the window is resized:

```
length  : Y.one('.slider-parent').getComputedStyle('width');
```

Add the event-resize module:

```
YUI().use('slider', 'event-resize' …
```

Resize logic:

```
Y.on('windowresize', function () { 
    slider.set('length', Y.one('.slider-parent').getComputedStyle('width'));
});
```